# Idols/Murti positions

Tags: idols

I don’t know if this has been asked before.

Why are some idols in standing position and some idols in sitting position in temples? Is there any logic behind the same?

I have always thought Ganesh Prabhu should always be in sitting position in temples however I have seen numerous temples where He is in standing position.

Are there any rules or explanation for the same?

Thanks.

Comment: It is determined mostly from the Dhyana Sloka of that particular deity. These Slokas describe in details about the appearances of the deities and everything else that is relevant. So from these Slokas we will know whether the deity should be in a seated posture or standing. But there is no guaranty that every idols that we see must have been crafted exactly as described in these Dhyana Slokas.

Comment: @Aham Sitting and standing are most common. What once started by a sculptor perhaps gets adopted later. Padmanabha in Trivandrum is in siesta, Ayyappa swamy sits with an unstable band around knees, the Nataraja has a dynamic Thandava pose balanced on a single foot and so on..Many idols do not have spines straight.